# Dynamic transformations on an inferred time-scale

Tags: time-series, modeling, data-transformation, fitting, cross-correlation

I have [two datasets](https://seafile.rlp.net/d/bd1b0744ed074953ab16/) which I am trying to correlate to one another. The first dataset, we'll call it `reference` records the dependant variable `Temperature` over independant discrete timestamps (monthly). The other dataset, let's call it `fit` has a dependent variable `Size` varying over an independent variable `Growth Distance`.

[image: Data to Transform]

I am trying to assign a timestamp to `fit.Growth Distance`. For that, I need to **"dynamically" transform it**, as the Growth measured here is a biological process, and growth is faster and slower at times, depending on environmental conditions. I read that this is called an irregularly sampled timeseries? So I would like to "stretch" areas with faster growth and "squeeze" areas with slower growth to better reflect the actual time.

`fit.Size` correlates very well with `reference.Temperature` and I am hoping to later derive that relationship via regression. I am however stuck at this "preprocessing" step, which I would need to have a common undependant time axis in both datasets.

My idea was to fit a trigonometric function to `d reference.Temperature/reference.Time` and then transform `fit.Growth Distance` to best fit this function. I also read into **Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)** but my problem with it is that I have ~5-10 times as many data points in `fit` than i have in `reference`. The easiest way I could imagine would be to determine the periodicity in `fit.Size` and make yearly maxima and minima equally spaced. But again, I have not enough knowledge to know how to accomplish this.

Any help at all would be very appreciated.